# The expression “I'll take it as take out”

Tags: expressions

If I order a coffee and want to take it out. (To go..) The expression "I'll take it as take out." makes sense? And use that in common?

Comment: The repetition of 'take' is awkward. 'I'll have it as take out' is better. Why don't you just say 'I'll have it to go'?

Answer (score 2):

The repetition of "take" is awkward, so your example is not the best choice.

When it comes to ordering food, sometimes you can just tack on a short phrase which is not a full sentence:

"to go"
"for take-out"
"for take-away" *chiefly British*

Adding the word "please" at the end is a good idea.

Of course, full sentences are also possible:

"I'd like it to go please."
"I'll have it to go."
"I'll have it as take-out."
"I'll take it to go."

Comment: I would not hyphenate “to go” unless using it as an adjective: “a to-go order”